# For which values of $\gamma>0$ do we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n k^\gamma=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, summation, divergent-series

I am interested in getting to know for which values of $\gamma >0$ we have that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n k^\gamma <\infty
$$

Or more specifically, for which values $\gamma$ does this limit vanishes.
A very bad bound gives us
\begin{align}
 \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n k^\gamma 
&\le
 \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n n^\gamma
\\&\le
 n^{1+\gamma-2} \longrightarrow 0
\end{align}
if $\gamma < 1 $. It is very likely that you can still have the same result for larger values, as in the bound used is very really bad to bound the first values.

Would anyone have a tip or maybe a reference?

Comment: For $\gamma =1$ and $\gamma = 2$ at least you can explicitly compute the limit.

Comment: Very true, for $\gamma =1$, the limit is already positive. So higher $\gamma>1$ would already be infinite. Thank you.

Comment: Write your sum $T_n$ as $T_n=n^{\gamma-1}S_n$, with $S_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n (\frac{k}{n})^{\gamma}$, and perhaps you know  something on $S_n$....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost done.  The sum is increasing in $\gamma$, so all you need to do is show that the limit is greater than zero when $\gamma=1$.

You can do this computation directly.